# Android-Activity- Should I set views to null on OnDestroy method?

Tags: android, android-activity

Let's say I have recyclerView, and Adapter and a textview in my activity.

Should I set these to null on OnDestroy method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    recyclerView=null;
    adapter=null;
    textview=null
}
```

Or activity does this for me?

Edit: This is my AsyncTask. I retrieve data from server.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> getUser = new ParseQuery<ParseUser>(ParseUser.class);
    getUser.whereEqualTo("username",usernameString);
    getUser.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) { 

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this but it's fine if you don't. GC will handle.

Comment: @Jaymin Thanks for answer Jaymin. But how about weakReferences? As far as I know I should use WeakReferences to avoid memory leaks in asyncTask. Should I set weak references to null or Garbage Collector handle that too?

Comment: To avoid the memory leaks in `Async`, You can cancel the `Async Task` when `onDestroy` is called.

Comment: @Jaymin I edited my question and added some sample asynctask that I use. How can I cancel it?

Comment: `getUser.cancel();` this is how you can cancel it. For more info have look at : https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#cancel--

Comment: @Jaymin Thank you very much

Comment: @Jaymin So If I use strong references to views in asynctask but cancel AsyncTask in OnDestroy method GC will collect my views right? So there wont be any memory leak?

Comment: Yes, GC will take care when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is - No, you do not need to set all references to null
`onDestroy()` is the last lifecycle method called before the activity object is destroyed. When an object is destroyed it automatically releases all references it holds.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But how about weakReferences? As far as I know I should use WeakReferences to avoid memory leaks in asyncTask. Should I set weak references to null or Garbage Collector handle that too?

Comment: WeakReference means that I don't consider the the WeakReference object as a dependency so GC don't use this reference in its dependency graph. Therefore, if any other object is not keeping a direct reference to this object GC automatically collects it for garbage. In Async case it is done in that way because the asynchronous operation lifetime can exceed the lifetime of the activity. However in cases like you asked system automatically destroys all the view hierarchy.